# Is this possible in expressJS?

Tags: typescript, express

> IFoo.ts

```
import { Request } from 'express';

export default interface IFoo extends Request {
    foo: any;
}
```

> middleware.ts

```
import { Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import IFoo from './IFoo';

function foo(req: IFoo, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log(req.foo); // want to access this req.foo in another file without using export.
}
```

I have three files `IFoo.ts`, `middleware.ts`, `access.ts` and i want to access **req.foo** in access.ts without using export statement. 
1. How can i do it? 
2. Is there any standard way of doing it? 
any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You couldn’t export it anyway. Why can’t you just call a function and pass it as a parameter?

Comment: It seems like you should be using middleware for this where your middleware looks at each incoming request and adds `req.foo` to it and then calls `next()` to continue further routing.  Then, any request handler that is after that middleware in order in any file can access `req.foo` without any import or exporting.  That's one of things things that middleware is used for.